# Return value from Q_INVOKABLE function In QtWebEngine

Tags: javascript, c++, qt5, qwebview, qwebkit

**Greeting**

Is there anyway to get return value of `Q_INVOKABLE` function in `Qt webEngine` without passing callback function ? ([Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html)) . Like what we were doing in `Qt WebKit` .

**More Information About Question**

In `QT4` and `Qt WebKit` i could get my function result as `QVariant` and cast it to `JSON` or any other type.

For example in my c++ project i have the following function that return application's version as `QVariant`.

```
Q_INVOKABLE QVariant getAppVersion();
```

I could simply use the following line in my `HTML` file and get result.

```
var applicationVersion = ApplicationObject.getAppVersion();
```

Now With `Qt 5.5` and `Qt WebEngine` i have to use following form in order to get the result.

```
ApplicationObject.getAppVersion(myResultFunction);

function myResultFunction(result){
     console.log(result);
}
```

I'm using `QT 5.5` And `Visual Studio 2013`.

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, There is not other way. You have to pass `callback` function.

But with using `promise` in `javascript`, It gets alot better!

Good luck